# Unable to pass password with space to shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, intel-edison

I have below script which turns on the tether mode on my intel edison.
But when I entered password with space it shows error that argument list is long. Without space it works perfectly fine

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SSID_FILE="/usr/share/apache2/htdocs/userhotspotname.conf"
if [ -s "$SSID_FILE" ]
then
    filename="/usr/share/apache2/htdocs/userhotspotname.conf"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == hotspotna* ]] ; then
            name=$(echo $line | grep "hotspotname" | cut -d= -f2)

        fi
        if [[ $line == hotspotpa* ]] ; then
            pass=$(echo $line | grep "hotspotpass" | cut -d= -f2)
            #pass="'${pass}'"
            echo $pass
        fi
        done < "$filename"
        **connmanctl tether wifi on "${name}" ${pass}**
fi
```

Below is userhotspotname.conf file content

```
hotspotname=cvg_space
hotspotpass=cgoma  pwd space
```

Since password is with space 
**connmanctl tether wifi on "${name}" ${pass}**
This command is failing since it is considering it as 4 arguments.
Please help in this if anyone has idea.

Comment: @tripleee I already tried using this but it is not working.  I not sure how to use "$*" in my case.

Comment: *Always* quote *all the things* [unless you know exactly what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). `echo "$pass"`

Comment: Oh, you also need to use `cut -f2-` to get more than just the second field if there would happen to be an equals sign in the value; or more succinctly, just read the values with `sed` instead of looping over the lines in the file with `while read -r`.

Comment: @tripleee I tried quoting "$pass" as well but it is still not working. I very new to shell. So please excuse if this sily question

Comment: @tripleee When I am trying to print value of pass it is printing fine.

Comment: I added another duplicate which should hopefully help. Several of the solutions in the answers there are severely over-engineered but one of the simple `awk -F= '$1 ~ /^hotspotna/ { $1=""; print }' filename` should work for you.

Comment: Then I guess you are not quoting it when you pass it to `connmanctl`.  *Always* quote *all the things.*

Comment: @tripleee Do you know how to quote argument with space while passing to shell command?

Comment: Read the link I posted earlier. `connmanctl tether wifi on "$name" "$pass"`

Comment: @tripleee I tried with connmanctl tether wifi on "$name" "$pass" but it still fails